# How to install software to another partition?

Tags: 16.04, android, partitioning, powershell

I dont have enough free space on my ubuntu partition(200MB free space to be precise) and but I want to install Android studio and powershell. I have 7-8GB free space on my other three partitions.How do I do it?

I know that ubuntu saves installed files in a tree-like format and saves everything in the same place so that duplication is avoided. But is there any way i could install those softwares in a different partition?

Comment: Please run `df -l` and paste it into your quaestion

Comment: Are you using LVM? Could you boot your host with a USB or DVD Ubuntu live? You can resize your LVM and/or partitions with it (using gparted, for example). You can soft link paths from another partitions or mount points inside your home directory too, using space from the other partition.

Answer (score 1):

1 ) go here 
[https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles)
and download the Android Studio in a tar.gz

2) go to terminal and type

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

3) move it to the other partition destination. Suposse your partition with freespace is /home

```
sudo mv android-studio.tar.gz /home
```

4) extract the file with the command

```
tar -zxvf android-studio.tar.gz (use the correct name)
```

5) In order to have this available from other locations create a launcher for the Android Studio, look here
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles

I hope this can help you! 
Comment if you have any trouble :)